# "Run on Server" throws error in Eclipse STS

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am new to Spring and I wanted to learn how to develop REST APIs using Spring so I have followed this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I click on the "Run on Server" and when I access "localhost:8080/greeting" I get:

The requested resource is not available.

Any clue why?

Regards

Comment: if you read both questions you see that they are different..

Comment: Answer from second question is valid for this. This guide is about creating executable JAR, do you have executable WAR?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [Working a Getting Started guide with STS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/)

Steps to Run app in STS

- Drag the entire application’s root folder down to the server instance.
- Click the Start button to start the app.
- You should see tc Server logging appear in one of the console windows.
- Right-click on the app, and select Open Home Page. A browser tab inside STS should open up and display the "Hello, world!" text.

If you want to Run app builded with guide [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) on server, then read guide [Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

For example you need to add web configuration

```
public class HelloWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: The server is running and the project is deployed but when I access the /greeting I get an error. The controller is not being called

Comment: That is the problem. I dont get any messages form the server after I start and deploy. Dont get this.. it is a working example, should be working out of the box :s

Comment: Do you have class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` in code added?

Comment: Which class? The Controller?

Comment: Take look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/. Did you read this?

Comment: Already did what is written there.

Comment: And what you have selected: initial or completed code sets?

Comment: In guide is written: **Click the Start button to start the app.**, Sorry, I think STS is overcomplicated, but this guide works. I have builded working apps based on this guide :)